# Rolling rigidbody cube in Unity3D

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

So in Unity3D I have a cube which is being controlled by a player(using arrows). Player can go wherever he wants with the cube. The problem is when I add rigidbody to the cube then it doesn't really go that smooth anymore, somehow at the end it just glitches. Tried to play a bit with `torque`, but that did not help or I do not understand yet clearly how to implement it correctly. This is the code I am using for the cube (it is written in JavaScript). Any help will be appreciated, even if you do not know the javascript an idea still counts. Thank you. Code :

```
private var ismoving : boolean = false;  
private var startY : float = 0;  
var cubeSpeed : float;  
var cubeSize : float;
var jumpHeight = 3.0;


function Update ()   
{  

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("up") && ismoving == false)  
    {  
        ismoving = true;  
        transform.Find("targetpoint").Translate(0, -cubeSize/2 , cubeSize/2);  
        StartCoroutine(DoRoll(transform.Find("targetpoint").position, Vector3.right, 90.0f,cubeSpeed));  

    }   
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("down") && ismoving == false)  
    {  
        ismoving = true;  
        transform.Find("targetpoint").Translate(0, -cubeSize/2, -cubeSize/2);  
        StartCoroutine(DoRoll(transform.Find("targetpoint").position, -Vector3.right, 90.0f,cubeSpeed));  
    }  
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("left") && ismoving == false)  
    {  
        ismoving = true;  
        transform.Find("targetpoint").Translate(-cubeSize/2, -cubeSize/2, 0);  
        StartCoroutine(DoRoll(transform.Find("targetpoint").position, Vector3.forward, 90.0,cubeSpeed));  
    }  
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("right") && ismoving == false)  
    {  
        ismoving = true;  
        transform.Find("targetpoint").Translate(cubeSize/2, -cubeSize/2, 0);  
        StartCoroutine(DoRoll(transform.Find("targetpoint").position, -Vector3.forward, 90.0f,cubeSpeed));     
    }  
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space") && ismoving == false)  
    {  

    GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().AddForce(new Vector3(0, jumpHeight, 0), ForceMode.Impulse);
    } 



}  

function DoRoll (aPoint, aAxis, aAngle, aDuration) {    

 var tSteps = Mathf.Ceil(aDuration * 30.0);  
 var tAngle = aAngle / tSteps;  
 var pos : Vector3; 

  for (var i = 1; i <= tSteps; i++)   
  {   
    transform.RotateAround (aPoint, aAxis, tAngle);  
    yield WaitForSeconds(0.0033333);  
  }   


   transform.Find("targetpoint").position = transform.position;  


   pos = transform.position;  
   pos.y = startY;  
   transform.position = pos;  


   var vec = transform.eulerAngles;  
   vec.x = Mathf.Round(vec.x / 90) * 90;  
   vec.y = Mathf.Round(vec.y / 90) * 90;  
   vec.z = Mathf.Round(vec.z / 90) * 90;  
   transform.eulerAngles = vec;  


   ismoving = false;       
}

 function FixedUpdate () {

}
```

Comment: Too many things wrong in your code. 1. Using Javascript instead of C#. 2. Not caching transform(Using .Find every time). 3. Not caching Rigibody. Please learn C#. It's not hard.

Comment: AndroidFreak, Unityscript is no longer available. You must change to c#.

Answer (score 4):

It's likely not moving smoothly because you are modifying its position and rotation `directly` with its **transform** instead of using `Rigidbody` functions.

Once `Rigidbody` is attached to it, **don't** use `transform.position = pos;` or `transform.eulerAngles = vec`;

`Rigidbody.MovePosition`, `Rigidbody.MoveRotation`, `Rigidbody.AddForce`, and `Rigidbody.AddTorque` are the functions you should be using.

Replace these in your `DoRoll` function

```
Rigidbody rb;
rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

rb.MovePosition(pos);
rb.MoveRotation(Quaternion.Euler(vec));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but when I do that it return this error:  'The best overload for the method 'UnityEngine.Rigidbody.MoveRotation(UnityEngine.Quaternion)' is not compatible with the argument list '(UnityEngine.Vector3)'.'

Comment: Also I have a question, can I really use Rigidbody.MoveRotation, because in documentation it says that it only reads an absolute value, but I have to rotate the cube by 90 degrees and i think Transform.Rotate does the trick. Am i wrong?

Comment: I am sorry if I am, I am just a beginner, trying to learn. Thank you :)

Comment: Once Rigidbody is attached to it, don't use transform.position = pos; or transform.eulerAngles = vec; or transform.SOMETHING...use rigidbody.SOMETHING to move the object. Learn C# to get further help. Modified the answer to compile.

Comment: @AndroidFreak So did this solution ever work for you?